# html horizontally unordered list - override by prestashop

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-lists, prestashop

I try to make a html table or a ul list to have a responsive gallery of pictures with text (links) below them. I do this in a CMS page from prestashop through page editing in source code.

I couldn't figure with tables, because prestashop si overwriting the rules and can't figure which one do that.

Here is the link for table one:
https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/ro/content/12-cataloage
It seems that it works on desktop but is not showing good on mobile. The table is wrong there.

Next step it was to try with ul and li as a list. I took example from here https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/ro/68-tipar-digital-offsset
where are a list of subcategories and being from the theme they show well.

The page that i test is here:
https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/ro/content/13-portofoliu

I tried to use 1 div with class="subcategories" then added a div with class="row". But none inherited prestashop css to make my list to be showed like native ones.
My list is stuck to vertical.

Also, is it better to make ul instead of a table for that gallery?
I need 2 pages with this type of simple galleries with not more than 50 pictures i think.
It is not a photo gallery. In catalog, it should show catalogs with links on pictures to the pdf and a text with link to a price list.

Used code:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="subcategories">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>
      <div class="subcategory-image">
        <a href="https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/ro/59-imbracaminte" title="IMBRACAMINTE" class="img">
          <img class="replace-2x" src="https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/img/cms/Accesorii_imbracaminte_subcategorie.jpg" alt="CATALOG 1">
        </a>
      </div>
    <h5>
      <a class="subcategory-name" href="https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/ro/69-print" title="PRINT">PRINT</a>
    </h5>
      <div class="cat_desc"><p>IMBRACAMINTE</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="subcategory-image">
        <a href="https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/ro/59-imbracaminte" title="IMBRACAMINTE" class="img">
          <img class="replace-2x" src="https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/img/cms/Imbracaminte_vara_subcategorie.jpg" alt="CATALOG 1">
        </a>
      </div>
    <h5>
      <a class="subcategory-name" href="https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/ro/69-print" title="PRINT">PRINT</a>
    </h5>
      <div class="cat_desc"><p>IMBRACAMINTE</p></div>
    </li>
      <li>
      <div class="subcategory-image">
        <a href="https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/ro/59-imbracaminte" title="IMBRACAMINTE" class="img">
          <img class="replace-2x" src="https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/img/cms/Imbracaminte_sport_subcategorie.jpg" alt="CATALOG 1">
        </a>
      </div>
    <h5>
      <a class="subcategory-name" href="https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/ro/69-print" title="PRINT">PRINT</a>
    </h5>
      <div class="cat_desc"><p>IMBRACAMINTE</p></div>
    </li>
      <li>
      <div class="subcategory-image">
        <a href="https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/ro/59-imbracaminte" title="IMBRACAMINTE" class="img">
          <img class="replace-2x" src="https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/img/cms/Imbracaminte_iarna_subcategorie.jpg" alt="CATALOG 1">
        </a>
      </div>
    <h5>
      <a class="subcategory-name" href="https://centrul-de-publicitate.ro/ro/69-print" title="PRINT">PRINT</a>
    </h5>
      <div class="cat_desc"><p>IMBRACAMINTE</p></div>
    </li>




  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I can't figure how to do that simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try maybe:

```
<style> ul { display: flex; } </style>
```

or better:

```
<style> .clearfix { display: flex; } </style>
```

Comment: It worked for horizontal alignment. But there are still issues.
I've added the following code for the ul (in prestashop global.css):

  .clearfix-bms {
    display: flex;
    margin-left:3em;
  }

  .cat_desc-bms {
    display: none;
  }
 
1. There is no space between them. I tried with margin-left from above. It hasn't worked neither with padding... Is moving all as a group.
2. On mobile is still looking bad. Is not responsive... i suppose is not taking the css from prestashop exactly where i need it to do that...

Comment: You can try with display: grid and add a second property grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto; now you will have 4 rows , to make it responsive add some media querys for example only 3 rows grid-template-columns: auto auto auto then for 2 rows use 2x auto for 1 row 1 auto

Comment: I tried that and it works. But i can't figured out how to put space between elements. They are stuck to each other.

Comment: With property "margin" you can add space around an objekt

Comment: hmm, it seems ok from time to time. I suppose it is prestashop cache with problems...

I got at some point the right view on mobile and on desktop too. I will try tomorrow with a clean cache.

I have css as follows:

Comment: `
.clearfix-bms-flex {
    display: flex;
    margin-left:3em;
  }

  .clearfix-bms-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 95%;
    padding-left: -15px;
    padding-right: -15px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .clearfix-bms-grid {
      grid-template-columns: auto; } 
  }

  .clearfix-bms-grid li{
    padding-left: -15px;
    padding-right: -15px;
    margin: 10px;
  }

  .cat_desc-bms {
    display: none;
  }
`

Comment: You can disable cache for Develop

Comment: here is an short guide for disable cache in google chrome... https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache

Comment: It seems that it works. I use firefox for working on websites. And the cache issue is from prestashop. I need to enable/disable Smart cache for CSS from performance for having instant css modifications. But it is smth from the hosting from what i see. After 10-15h it works ok.

So, this last answer helped to make the list go well on desktop and mobile too. With the new classes that i've added and your css settings it works for now. I will go with the real photos and links and will be back if i have other issues.

Thanks so much for your solutions.

Comment: No Problem, i am here to help

Comment: I can't vote yet, so i will come back when i'll be able to do that. I need more rep ;-)

Comment: You have only 1 media query i see but you could add 3 from 4 rows to 3, 2 and 1 . You shrink your screen and see how much you can shrink it till your img almost touch the device border , then you make there your first media query for grid-template-columns: auto auto auto; then you continue shrinking your site till your img almost touch your screen border then add there another media query for grid-template-columns: auto auto; anf so on....

Comment: Yes i saw that and i installed a ruler to see the dimensions when resizing the window (i was using inspector to check smth) ;-). 
I think i will make for 2 or 3 columns but don't know yet for what resolutions... 
The most important think is that i made it to work.